# How to store a collection of strings in jdo apache isis without joins

Tags: jdo, isis

I wanted to store a set of strings which are not available in any other table in the schema. For example,

I have a table with country_id, country_name and animals

The column animals need to be a Collection (Set or List) and the animals in the list are not available in any other table of the schema. They are just plain java strings. I went through the link [here](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jdo/orm/one_to_many_collection.html). But it only mentions the ways to store a collection of objects that are available as a column in another table. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a JDO `AttributeConverter`, and the Collection field can be converted into a String for example (stored in a single column). As per [the docs](http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jdo/mapping.html#one_many_nonpc_converter)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I tried using the class but I keep getting error that the package cannot be resolved. Which package should I use?

Comment: It is part of JDO 3.2, so you need to be using that

Comment: You will need to use Apache Isis 2.0.0-M1 or later, because that uses DN 5.x and JDO 3.2